# How can I plot fitted lines of a mixed model with a large number of clusters?

Tags: ggplot2

I am working with a longitudinal data set with measurements of growth of several hundred individuals. I am using the lme4 and pedigreemm R packages for the modelling part. I would like to plot the fitted lines of a linear mixed effect model. However, I would only like to visualise a small subset of the individuals to make the graph readable. I hope this is not a silly question, but I was not able to find any such example online.

I used this function to plot the measurements with a linear trend line.

```
ggplot(data_subset, aes(x = age, y = mass, colour = id)) + geom_point() 
+ geom_smooth(method = "lm") + facet_wrap( ~ id)
```

I would like to do the same thing only use the fitted line from the model this time.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you are fitting the following growth model, which has linear (age0), quadratic (age2) and cubic (age3) fixed effect predictors and then a random slope for age0:

`m2 <- lmer(weight ~ female + age0 + age2 + age3 + (age0 | id), growth, REML=FALSE)`

You can pull the population level and individual level predictions from this model as such:

```
growth$predm2 <- predict(m2,re.form=NA)  ## population level
growth$predm2fit <- predict(m2) ## individual level
```

First, you can plot the population trend, here I am plotting it separately for boys and girls:

```
g1 <- ggplot(growth,aes(age0, weight)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(.~female) #   

g1 + geom_line(colour="red",aes(y=predm2))
```

[image: Population growth trajectory separately for boys and girls]

Now you can plot the individual trend lines, which take into account the random intercept and slope:

```
g1 + geom_line(colour="red",aes(y=predm2)) + 
  geom_line(colour="dark grey",aes(y=predm2fit,group=id)) # fitted lines
```

[image: Individual growth trajectory separately for boys and girls]

P.S. You can grab this data to play with it yourself:

```
library(haven)
growth <- read_dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/mlmus2/asian.dta")
growth <- growth %>% mutate(age0 = age-min(age), female = gender-1)
as_data_frame(growth)
```

P.P.S., in case you want to randomly sample a subset of cases, you can use the `sample` function as part of a `filter` in `dplyr`:

```
#Sampling 50 students
JSP_long50 <- JSP_long %>%
  mutate(StudentID=as.factor(StudentID)) %>%
  filter(StudentID %in% sample(levels(StudentID),50))
```